# How well supported is .NET on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mono, c#

I have to port an application written in C# + WinForms to run on Ubuntu. But how well is .NET and WinForms supported on Ubuntu? If I take a C#.NET + WinForms project and try to compile under Ubuntu 14, will it not work under these circumstances? I've hear about .NET under Linux but I don't know how far it has been done or is mono still the only way?

I'd really, really like to avoid rewrite the entire application in C++ and Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new .Net on Linux you may have heard about is called [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core). It should be well supported, but it is a subset of .Net Framework, targeted primarily at web and cloud applications, and does not support WinForms (or any other UI library).

So, if you want to run a WinForms application on Linux, Mono is still your best option. Using that may work for you or it may not. [Miguel de Icaza said in 2014](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2014-March/050721.html) (and I assume nothing has changed since then):

> Mono has an implementaiton of Windows.Forms, but it is both old,
>   unmaintainted and known to have some bugs.
>
> Some people have been able to use it effectively, but we do not currently
>   have an active maintainer, so we encourage developers to pick something
>   like Gtk# instead.